# Homotopy groups of quotient by a discrete group

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, group-actions

Suppose $X$ is some contractible space and $\Gamma$ a discrete topological group acting continuously on $X$. Is it possible for $X/\Gamma$ to have non-trivial higher homotopy groups $\pi_k$, $k\geq2$?

If the action is nice then $\Gamma \to X \to X/\Gamma$ should be a fibre bundle and the long exact sequence gives $\pi_k(X)=0\to\pi_k(X/\Gamma)\to\pi_{k-1}(\Gamma) = 0$ for $k\geq2$, since $\Gamma$ is discrete and $X$ contractible and so $\pi_k(X/\Gamma) = 0$ for $k\geq2$.

Comment: Hint: Consider discrete isometric groups of the Eucludean plane. Can the quotient be the 2-sphere?

Comment: @MoisheKohan if it were possible, then the 2-sphere would be almost everywhere flat, except in some singular points, roughly speaking? But I don't see how this should be possible. Maybe I am too stupid.

Comment: Think more about groups generated by rotations...

Comment: @MoisheKohan so, maybe, then we could first get the 2-torus as quotient, and then rotate the torus by $\pi$. This should give the 2-sphere? The 2-torus we get by 2 independent translations and with the rotation this gives a discrete subgroup $\Gamma$. The translations $\Gamma_0\leq \Gamma$ are normal, and then we can build $\mathbb{R}^2/\Gamma = ((\mathbb{R}^2)/\Gamma_0)/(\Gamma/\Gamma_0) = T^2/\mathbb{Z}_2$.?

Comment: Just make sure the rotation has 4 fixed points.

Comment: @MoisheKohan So, if we have a square, and identify opposite sites, we have the torus. This square we rotate about the middle point by $\pi$. Then, if we divide this square into 4 equal squares, the four corner points of one little square are fixed and $T^2/\mathbb{Z}_2 = S^2$? Is there maybe some literature where such non-free group actions are studied? And has this something to do with covering theory, so is there a theory like that, because it seems that this is similar?

Comment: Read about 2-dimensional orbifolds.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Ok, thank you very much!

Comment: If you've figured out an answer from the comments then you should post it as an answer